# Get the file list of a folder with Dir

Tags: excel, vba, windows, file, directory

I'm trying to get the file list of a folder in VBA

The DIR command acts as if the * wildcard is messing up the whole mask that I input.

Here is my file list:

- NotAText.inf
- Sample1.txt
- Sample2.txt
- Sample3.txt
- Sample4.txt1
- Sample5.txta

The original mask I tried is "`*.txt`"
I **should** get 3 files.
Instead I get: the 3 ***.txt*** files and both the ***.txt1*** and ***.txta*** files.

I tested with other filenames and extensions, if I use question marks only, it works OK, e.g.:
Mask: "`???????.txt`" returns the 3 ***.txt*** files as it should.

Systems tried on:
Windows 11; Excel version: 2112
Windows 10; Excel version: 2102
Windows 98; Excel 97

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    
    i = 1
    
    s = Dir("*.txt")
    
    Do While (s <> "")
        Cells(i, 1) = s
        s = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Fresh find: if I use a file extension longer than 3 characters as a filter, it works OK, it only returns the required files. I found under Windows 98's command prompt that Windows treats a 3-character file extension filter as a "base" and treats similar files (beginning with that filter) as "TXT" as well, I suppose this is true for modern Windows versions too, that's why the fault exists. My guess is, when a 3-character extension filter is used, it searches using the 8.3 filename format, when a longer one is used, it searches using the proper long-filename. Did I just find an ancient Windows bug???

```
SAMPLE1  TXT             0  21.12.14  12.04 Sample1.txt
SAMPLE2  TXT             0  21.12.14  12.04 Sample2.txt
SAMPLE3  TXT             0  21.12.14  12.04 Sample3.txt
SAMPLE~1 TXT             0  21.12.14  12.04 Sample4.txt1
SAMPLE~2 TXT             0  21.12.14  12.04 Sample5.txta
```

Interesting fact: under PowerShell, the command works with a 3-character extension filter.

Comment: It's not an ancient bug, it's a feature, `Dir` (both on command line and in VBA)  looks also to the file shortname (8.3 format) that windows keeps for compatibility reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66674420/7599798 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/68287857/7599798

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: WildCard \* - find a file ending to a digit - finds the wrong file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674420/vba-wildcard-find-a-file-ending-to-a-digit-finds-the-wrong-file)

Comment: FWIW, that phenomenon does NOT occur using `Application.GetOpenFileName`:  eg `Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")` will return only `.txt` files and not `.txt1` etc

Comment: Consider using FSO (File System Object), allows you to access the file extension directly so you don't need wildcards.

Comment: @FunThomas Indeed, it does. I did not find this, and the automatic suggestions did not return it either. Many thanks for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had a problem with Dir but for your needs try something like this -

```
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String, sPath As String, sFilter As String
    
    i = 1
    sPath = CurDir & "\"
    sFilter = "*.txt"    
    s = Dir(sPath, 15)
    
    Do While Len(s)
        If LCase(s) Like sFilter Then
            Cells(i, 1) = s
            i = i + 1
        End If
        s = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This will probably be the ultimate and easiest solution we'll use. Thanks.