Dir function not returning all files or directories in directory
I am attempting to traverse a directory and all of its subfolders to produce a dictionary of file paths and md5 hashes. While I do get some of the files, I am always missing several hundred other files and a handful of folders. Some of these files are even in directories where other files get read fine.
Option Explicit

Public Const HostFolder As String = "C:\Users\USERPLACEHOLDER\Downloads\Folder 1\"
Public Const TargetFolder As String = "C:\Users\USERPLACEHOLDER\Downloads\Folder 2\"


Sub RunFolder()
    Dim hostFiles As Dictionary
    Dim hostFolders As Collection
    Set hostFiles = New Dictionary
    Set hostFolders = New Collection
    
    TraversePath HostFolder, hostFiles, hostFolders
    
    Dim targetFiles As Dictionary
    Dim targetFolders As Collection
    Set targetFiles = New Dictionary
    Set targetFolders = New Collection
    
    TraversePath TargetFolder, targetFiles, targetFolders
    
    Dim copyDict As Dictionary
    Set copyDict = targetFiles
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    
    Debug.Print hostFiles.count
    Debug.Print targetFiles.count
    
    For Each x In hostFiles.Keys
        If targetFiles.Exists(x) Then
            If hostFiles.Item(x) = targetFiles.Item(x) Then
                hostFiles.Remove x
                targetFiles.Remove x
            Else
                Debug.Print x & ":::" & hostFiles.Item(x) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "MD5 hash does not match"
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print x & " does not exist in the target files"
        End If
    Next
    
    For Each x In copyDict
        If hostFiles.Exists(x) Then
            If copyDict.Item(x) = hostFiles.Item(x) Then
                hostFiles.Remove x
                copyDict.Remove x
            Else
                Debug.Print x & ":::" & copyDict.Item(x) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "MD5 hash does not match2"
            End If
        Else
            'x
        End If
    Next
    
    For Each x In hostFiles
        Debug.Print x & ":::" & hostFiles.Item(x)
    Next
    
    Debug.Print hostFiles.count
    Debug.Print targetFiles.count
    
    For Each y In hostFolders
        Debug.Print y
    Next
End Sub

Sub TraversePath(ByVal path As String, ByRef fileDict As Dictionary, ByRef folderColl As Collection)
    Dim currentPath As String, directory As Variant
    Dim dirCollection As Collection
    Set dirCollection = New Collection
    
    currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
    
    'Explore current directory
    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        'Debug.Print path & currentPath
        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And _
            (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            dirCollection.Add currentPath
        ElseIf currentPath <> "." And currentPath <> ".." Then
            fileDict.Add Right(path & currentPath, Len(path & currentPath) - Len(HostFolder)), FileToMD5(path & currentPath) 'TODO: Adjust the len, both folders will not be same length
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'Explore subsequent directories
    For Each directory In dirCollection
        'Debug.Print "---SubDirectory: " & directory & "---"
        folderColl.Add Right(path & directory & "\", Len(path & directory & "\") - Len(HostFolder))
        TraversePath path & directory & "\", fileDict, folderColl
    Next directory
End Sub

'Make sure that Net Framework 3.5 (includes .Net 2 and .Net 3) is installed and enabled
'and not only the Net Framework 4.8 Advanced Services

Public Function FileToMD5(sFullPath As String) As String
    Dim enc, bytes, outstr As String, pos As Integer
    
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
    'Convert the string to a byte array and hash it
    bytes = GetFileBytes(sFullPath)
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((bytes))
    
    FileToMD5 = ConvToHexString(bytes)
        
    Set enc = Nothing

End Function

Private Function GetFileBytes(ByVal sPath As String) As Byte()
    Dim lngFileNum As Long, bytRtnVal() As Byte, bTest
    
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    
    If LenB(Dir(sPath)) Then ''// Does file exist?
        
        Open sPath For Binary Access Read As lngFileNum
        
        'a zero length file content will give error 9 here
        On Error Resume Next 'TODO: Remove this later?
        
        ReDim bytRtnVal(0 To LOF(lngFileNum) - 1&) As Byte
        Get lngFileNum, , bytRtnVal
        Close lngFileNum
    Else
        Err.Raise 53 'File not found
    End If
    
    GetFileBytes = bytRtnVal
    
    Erase bytRtnVal

End Function

Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim oD As Object
      
    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
      
      With oD
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")
    
    Set oD = Nothing

End Function

This is the code I am using exactly as I have it so hopefully this allows you to reproduce my errors.

I don't believe Dir works recursively.

@BigBen It does not, however the dirCollection holds the directories. So the function is still recursive.

Maybe rephrasing, I don't believe Dir can be used recursively.

A bit difficult to repro without your files?  Are the same files always missing?  Maybe those files are read-only?

@TimWilliams The same files and folders are always missing. They are not read-only as far as the windows property window tells me. If it helps the file extensions are .par .lim and variations of .par and .lim with timestamps at the end of them.

In that case a few of those files in a folder and a much simpler script might be easier to troubleshoot?

Could be an issue with short vs long names, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674917/7599798. If I were you, I would use FileSystemObject.
